# Based on dropdown select value populate input text fields and initially it should have 2 input fields

Tags: javascript, html

Problem is initially it should show 2 input text fields and based on drop down select it should add or remove input fields.
and dropdown menu start with 2 till 6.

**My Code:**

```
function addElements(selectElement) {
  var textboxNumbers = selectElement.value;
  var dsets = document.getElementById("dsets");
  var dmenu = document.getElementById("textboxes");

  dsets.innerHTML = ""; //Empty "dsets" element

  for (var i = 0; i < textboxNumbers; i++) {
    var yourTextboxes = document.createElement("INPUT");
    yourTextboxes.setAttribute("type", "textbox"+"<br>");
    yourTextboxes.setAttribute("id", "dsid"+(i+1));
    yourTextboxes.setAttribute("placeholder", "DataSet Name "+(i+1));
    yourTextboxes.setAttribute("style", "height: 25px; width: 250px;");
    dsets.appendChild(yourTextboxes);
  }
  document.getElementById("textboxes").style.display = '';
}
```

```
<td><select class="displaymenu" onclick="addElements(this)" id="textboxes">
  <option>Please Select</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Expected:**

[image]

Any Help will be much appreciated...

Comment: If initially it should have 2 input fields then why it has only one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not added `<div id="dsets"></div>` to hold the output to append.

Also use `onchange` event for **select boxes**. I have changed it.

Add `selected` to the select box, it will select the default option and trigged the selected options change event in default state.

#### Try below Code

```js
function addElements(selectElement) {
    var textboxNumbers = selectElement.value;
    var dsets = document.getElementById("dsets");
    var dmenu = document.getElementById("textboxes");

    dsets.innerHTML = ""; //Empty "dsets" element

    for (var i = 0; i < textboxNumbers; i++) {
        var yourTextboxes = document.createElement("INPUT");
        var linebreak = document.createElement("br");

        yourTextboxes.setAttribute("type", "textbox" + "<br>");
        yourTextboxes.setAttribute("id", "dsid" + (i + 1));
        yourTextboxes.setAttribute("placeholder", "DataSet Name " + (i + 1));
        yourTextboxes.setAttribute("style", "height: 25px; width: 250px;");
        dsets.appendChild(yourTextboxes);
        dsets.appendChild(linebreak);
    }
    document.getElementById("textboxes").style.display = '';
}

var event = new Event('change');
var element = document.querySelector(".displaymenu");
element.dispatchEvent(event);
```

```html
<table>
    <td><select class="displaymenu" onchange="addElements(this)" id="textboxes">
            <option>Please Select</option>
            <option selected>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
            <option>6</option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="dsets"></div>
```

Hope this will helps.

Comment: but my problem is without selecting any dropdown value it should show 2 input fields initially.

Comment: @akshay I have modified code snippet try once

Comment: thanks for responding I tried your same code on Jsfiddle, after running the code it is not showing input fields initially also getting error as - "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'dispatchEvent')"".

this one I also tried by flask rendering getting same.

Comment: @akshay Share Fiddle URL

Comment: Hi mahesh that issue is resolved now in option I've used selected="selected". Just one more add to this how can we add these input fields in next line instead of side by side.

Comment: @akshay welcome. "how can we add these input fields in next line instead of side by side" => Check I have updated the code above you can use `var linebreak = document.createElement("br");` and append any element like this.

Comment: Hi Mahesh if I fill text in input field for ex. by selecting "2" I filled text in input field and again I choose "3" then the filled data is vanished...!!.
How to fix this can you pls. help me in this. It should have filled text data.

Comment: Yes because here inputs are recreated on change you need to create all input at once and need to just hide and show as per it required onchange

Comment: Couldn't get you I'm rookie in javascript..

Comment: @akshay try by yourself once if you stuck then you can come back with whatever you have tried and let we try to resolve your issue. 

So here first you need to create elements and hide it by adding css display none and `onchange` event you have to hide show that elements. And create separate quotation when you tried anything.